# Is there an equivalent to ST_Rotate in spatialite?

Tags: spatialite

I'd like to do some arbitrary rotation of spatial objects in spatialite (accessed through QGIS). In PostGIS I'd use something like:

```
...
SELECT geom AS ST_Rotate(geom, radians, originX, originY)
```

Is there an equivalent in spatialite?

---

Edit: after the answer and some more research, managed to find a way of mimicing `ST_Rotate` using `ShiftCoords` and `RotateCoords`, rotating by 45° around the centroid in the example below:

```
SELECT ShiftCoords(RotateCoords(ShiftCoords(GEOMETRY, 
 -X(Centroid(GEOMETRY)), -Y(Centroid(GEOMETRY))), 45), 
 X(Centroid(GEOMETRY)), Y(Centroid(GEOMETRY))) AS geom from TABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent, however you should be able to do something similar with a combination of RotateCoords() which rotates the geometry (in degrees, rather than radians), ShiftCoords() and ScaleCoords().

Here is an example, simplified from the test suite:

```
SELECT AsText(RotateCoords(geom, 0)), AsText(RotateCoords(geom, 90.0)), AsText(RotateCoords(geom, 180.0)), AsText(RotateCoords(geom, -90)) FROM (SELECT GeomFromText("POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 1 2, -1 1, 0 0))") as geom) dummy;
POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 1 2, -1 1, 0 0))
POLYGON((0 0, 1 -1, 2 -1, 1 1, 0 0))
POLYGON((0 0, -1 -1, -1 -2, 1 -1, 0 0))
POLYGON((0 0, -1 1, -2 1, -1 -1, 0 0))
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like I need to create a custom function that shifts the centroid (or centre of extent) to 0,0, does the rotation, then shifts back.

Comment: ... except that it turns out there is no way to make [custom functions in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8283265/975540).